# @font-face not cooperating in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, fonts, font-face

I have tried numerous things, including clicking on ALL of the questions related to my question (there were tons!) and tried all of their "solutions" but none worked for me. I tried wrapping the .eot file in a conditional IE statement but that didn't work either. Somebody said that @font-face won't work in Firefox if your not hosting the file on your own server... Or something like that. Anyway, go [here](http://roseanneconner.tumblr.com/page/1) to see the comparison between all other browsers vs Firefox. Please don't bash! I really did try every solution Google and stackoverflow had to offer. (Keep in mind that this is a Tumblr theme, and all files/images must be hosted via [Tumblr's uploader](http://www.tumblr.com/themes/upload_static_file) .)

Thanks in advance!

Also, here is the code I have been using:

```
<!--[if IE]>
<style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'S';
src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/5bTlflus9/zegoelight-u-webfont.eot');
}
</style>
<![endif]-->

<style>
@font-face {
font-family: 'S';
src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/5bTlflus9/zegoelight-u-webfont.eot');
src: local('S'), 
     local('S'), 
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/n4Zlfluv6/zegoelight-u-webfont.ttf')      
format('truetype'),
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/ovQlfluz3/zegoelight-u-webfont.svg#font')    
format('svg'); 
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/1AJlfluwz/zegoelight-u-webfont.woff')
format('woff');
}
</style>
```

I tried going to about:config in Firefox and toggling security.fileuri.strict_origin_policy to false but it didn't work. Plus I need a way so all users who view my theme or use it to be able to view the font as well, and that is set to true by default.

Comment: By trying to get one of the fonts via the urls I encounter `The image “...zegoelight-u-webfont.ttf” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.` in Firefox. So it seems to be that Tumblr screws it up by serving the files as `image/jpeg`.

Comment: What are those HTML conditional comments doing within your CSS?

Comment: Sorry they are actually seperate parts of my code, I just put them together. Fixed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit:

Here is the solution:
[Cross domain workaround](http://geoff.evason.name/2010/05/03/cross-domain-workaround-for-font-face-and-firefox/)

Firefox does not like cross domain embedding.

Answer (score 1):

Earl, I hate to be one to tell you this but your problem isn't with your @font-face rule. At least it wasn't when I checked out your site. When you use CSS font-family you need to make sure there is a comma between each different font in your chosen stack.
Your h6 selector was:

```
h6 {font-size:36px; font-family: 'S' sans-serif;}
```

It should be:

```
h6 {font-size:36px; font-family: 'S', sans-serif;}
```

Give this a try and I think it will work out for your. Just make sure all of your font-family stacks have commas in between multiple fonts. Firefox is a bit more strict with parsing technically incorrect CSS; Firefox just ignores it. That appears to be why you are having a problem, not your @font-face.

Comment: This did not solve the problem, but thanks for correcting me :) I would rather have good code than ok code.

Comment: Strange, it worked for me. Sorry that didn't solve your problem.

Comment: I figure it is because of Tumblr, itself :(

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely convinced by your @font-face rule.  Can you copy the following and see what (if any) difference it makes?  Just to clean things up.

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'S';
src: url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/5bTlflus9/zegoelight-u-webfont.eot');
src: local('☺'),
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/n4Zlfluv6/zegoelight-u-webfont.ttf')      
format('truetype'),
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/ovQlfluz3/zegoelight-u-webfont.svg#font')    
format('svg'); 
     url('http://static.tumblr.com/ctwb3zj/1AJlfluwz/zegoelight-u-webfont.woff')
format('woff');
}
```

That just cleans a couple of minor things up.  I'd also suggest changing your font name to something other than "S"; "Zegoe Light", for example.

Ivo Wetzel is correct from your comments though, this may be an issue with the way Tumblr serves up media with unknown file extensions.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar problem, it worked everywhere, but not in Firefox4 on a Mac. I declared the @font-face-Stuff inside another @media block (only loading fonts for non-mobile devices) - and that's what caused the error.

This didn't work:

```
@media sth... {

  @font-face {
    ...
  }

}
```

This did work:

```
@font-face {
  ..
}

@media sth... {

}
```

Comment: I actually figured it out a long time ago. The best way to do it is when you download the font-squirrel files it comes with the css stylesheet. You need to open it up in your browser and view the source then click on one of the stylesheets in the code and it will lead you to the font embed. Copy and paste that into a notepad and then upload the font files from font-squirrel into Tumblr's static uploader and use the urls from the uploads in place of the ones in the embed and then use that stylesheet in your theme.