# @font-face on Squarespace not displaying in firefox

Tags: html, css, fonts, font-face, squarespace

I'm building a site on Squarespace, and i'm trying to implement some fonts using the @font-face command. I can get it to work properly in Chrome and Safari, but not in Firefox.

Here is my code...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: "Stagger Medium";
  src: url("/storage/fonts/stagger/medium/staggermedium.eot");
src: local("?"),
  url("/storage/fonts/stagger/medium/staggermedium.woff") format("woff"),
  url("/storage/fonts/stagger/medium/Stagger%20Medium.otf") format("opentype"),
}
```

Any ideas?

Edit:
I've seen some things mentioning Cross-Site Font Usage using access control headers. Is that a possibility? I'm not entirely sure how to implement that though.

Edit:
I've also read that if you put the fonts in the same directory as the website, then it shouldn't be a problem in Firefox. HOWEVER, i'm using Squarespace, so I can only store the font in the STORAGE directory, which is separate from where the site is located.

Comment: Do any of [these solutions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4800794/font-face-not-cooperating-in-firefox) help you?

Comment: The solution that seems to be working the best there is uploading to Font Squirrel and using the 64bit encoding. The font I want to use won't work on font squirrel.

Comment: Have you tried setting local to "Stagger Medium"?

Comment: I've seen some things mentioning Cross-Site Font Usage using access control headers. Is that a possibility? I'm not entirely sure how to implement that though.

Comment: I've also read that if you put the fonts in the same directory as the website, then it shouldn't be a problem in Firefox. HOWEVER, i'm using Squarespace, so I can only store the font in the STORAGE directory, which is separate from where the site is located.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry, it was actually the opposite, remove the full url:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" 
    href="/storage/css/fonts.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8">
```

I put both just to be safe.